# Rails 4: ActiveRecord or MySQL query where no related models have attribute

Tags: mysql, sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

Having a tough time with this one.  I have a Job model, and a JobStatus model. A job has many statuses, each with different names (slugs in this case).  I need an 'active' method I can call to find all jobs where none of the associated statuses has a slug of 'dropped-off'.

```
class Job < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :agent

  has_many :statuses, :class_name => "JobStatus"

    validates :agent_id,
                        :pickup_lat,
                        :pickup_lng,
                        :dropoff_lat,
                        :dropoff_lng,
                        :description,
                        presence: true

    class << self

        def by_agent agent_id
            where(agent_id: agent_id)
        end

        def active
            #
            # this should select all items where no related job status 
            # has the slug 'dropped-off'
            #
        end

    end

end
```

Job Status:

```
class JobStatus < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :job

  validates :job_id,
                    :slug,
                    presence: true
end
```

The closest I've gotten so far is:

```
def active
     joins(:statuses).where.not('job_statuses.slug = ?', 'dropped-off')
end
```

But it's still selecting the Job that has a dropped-off status because there are previous statuses that are not 'dropped-off'. If i knew the raw sql, I could probably work it into activerecord speak but I can't quite wrap my head around it.

Also not married to using activerecord, if the solution is raw SQL that's fine too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Job.where.not(id: JobStatus.where(slug: 'dropped-off').select(:job_id))
```

will generate a nested subquery for you.

Comment: For the record, the generated query was: SELECT `jobs`.* FROM `jobs`  WHERE (`jobs`.`id` NOT IN (SELECT `job_statuses`.`job_id` FROM `job_statuses`  WHERE `job_statuses`.`slug` = 'dropped-off'))

Answer (score 1):

Not the cleanest method, but you could use two queries.

```
# Getting the ID of all the Jobs which have 'dropped-off' JobStatuses
dropped_off_ids = JobStatus.where(slug: 'dropped-off').pluck(:job_id)

# Using the previous array to filter the Jobs
Job.where.not(id: dropped_off_ids)
```

Comment: While this would work it also wouldn't scale... I'm definitely looking for a single-query option, for potentially millions of records. Thanks for the response though!

Comment: So maybe `Job.where.not(id: JobStatus.where(slug: 'dropped-off').pluck(:job_id).to_sql)` ? (nested query)

Comment: MrYoshiji, the resultant query is "SELECT `jobs`.* FROM `jobs`  WHERE (`jobs`.`id` NOT IN (3, 4, 3, 3))" which does work, however won't scale well in there are thousands or millions of job statuses (the NOT IN array would be approximately as long).

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
def active
  Job.joins(:statuses).where.not('job_statuses.slug' => 'dropped-off')
end
```

or this:

```
def active
  Job.joins(:statuses).where('job_statuses.slug != ?', 'dropped-off')
end
```

Comment: Thanks San, but unfortunately I've already tried these - see above for the issue I noticed with this approach.

Comment: The queries that I wrote are not exactly the same as yours. Are you sure you have tried these? And, what do you mean when you say "previous statuses are not 'dropped-off'"?

Comment: Yes, these are still picking up jobs that do have a slug of 'dropped-off', because they have previous statuses that have a slug that are not 'dropped-off'. For example, there a statuses that reference the job with slugs like 'picked-up', etc.

Comment: Are you saying that one `status` has multiple slugs?

Comment: One job has many statutses, and slug is a property on status.

Answer (score 0):

I think you may want to reevaluate your data model somewhat. If the problem is that you're turning up old statuses when asking about Job, you likely need to have column identifying the current status for any job, i.e. `job.statuses.where(current_status: true)`

Then you can very easily grab only the rows which represent the current status for all jobs and are not "dropped-off".

Alternatively, if I'm misunderstanding your use case and you're just looking for *any* job that has ever had that status, you can just go backwards and search for the status slugs first, i.e.

```
JobStatus.where.not(slug: "dropped-off").map(&:job)
```